# Why does vim jump down to same position after multiple spaces?

Tags: vim, whitespace

I really can't find the answer to this and I would like to understand what going on behind the scenes to make this happen.  Is it a setting I have switched on? If so, which one?

To give an example, I needed to create a file containing several lines of just spaces, but each time I pressed enter at the end of the line, instead of the cursor going to the beginning of the next line, it just went down directly under its current position.

This wasn't a `vim` task, I'm just trying to use the editor as much as possible for practice .

Comment: Are you in insert mode? If not, vim shows the described behaviour

Comment: »vi is not an editor« — »What is it then?« — »I think it makes music. All I seem to get from it is beeps.« ;)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have `smartindent` or `autoindent` enable in your `.vimrc` file. You can turn off it for current session by typing:

```
:set nosmartindent
:set noautoindent
```

in command mode, or make it persistent in your `.vimrc` file:

```
set nosmartindent
set noautoindent
```

You can also just remove `set smartindent` or `set autoindent` line in `.vimrc` to turn `smartindent` or `autoindent` off because vim by default has turned off them:

```
'smartindent' 'si'      boolean (default off)
                        local to buffer
                        {not in Vi}
                        {not available when compiled without the
                        +smartindent feature}
....
'autoindent' 'ai'       boolean (default off)
                        local to buffer
```

Comment: Could also be `autoindent`

Comment: @Bernhard: No, if you turn off `autoindent` but turn on `smartindent`, the OP's problem still occurs.

Comment: I mean that if you only have a `set autoindent` in `.vimrc`, then you encounter the same problem. He should not look for only `smartindent` in the `.vimrc`. I am not trying to claim that your answer is wrong.

Comment: @Bernhard: Ah, yes of course. My mistake when thinking that only one option is used. I will update my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I'm a she by the way :)
I do have auto indent set in vimrc. Well, there was an easy explanation. Thanks guys, I wouldn't have thought of it though on my own (at least not for some time), as I'm still getting the hang of it.
Much appreciated!